# Why project with Gitlab CI/CD doesn't build?

Tags: python-3.x, gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd, .env

I am trying to add CI/CD to my django project with docker.

To add CI/CD I found out that I need to create new `.env` variable for my `docker-compose.yml` service's apps:

```
NEW_VAR=$CI_REGISTRY/<gitlab username>/<repository name>/custom_image:$CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG-$CI_COMMIT_SHA
```

Added images to apps:

```
services:
  app:
    image: ${NEW_VAR}
    env_file:
      - .env
    # ...

  bot:
    image: ${NEW_VAR}
    env_file:
      - .env
    # ...
```

Made `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
# ...

before_script:
  - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
  - cp $DOT_ENV $(pwd)/.env

# ...
```

And created and linked runner to my repository. But when I ran `docker compose up` on my PC I got error:

```
WARN[0000] The "lqxwj" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "CI_REGISTRY" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "CI_COMMIT_SHA" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "lqxwj" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "CI_REGISTRY" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "CI_COMMIT_SHA" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "lqxwj" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "CI_REGISTRY" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "CI_COMMIT_SHA" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "lqxwj" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "CI_REGISTRY" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "CI_COMMIT_SHA" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "lqxwj" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "CI_REGISTRY" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "CI_COMMIT_SHA" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
Error response from daemon: invalid reference format
```

I can't understand why. `.env` in the same diroctory as `Dockerfile`, `.gitlab-ci.yml` and `docker-compose.yml`. Before this `NEW_VAR` everything worked fine.

Tried to run `docker compose build` and got:

```
time="2023-04-26T18:45:50+05:00" level=warning msg="The \"lqxwj\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2023-04-26T18:45:50+05:00" level=warning msg="The \"CI_REGISTRY\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2023-04-26T18:45:50+05:00" level=warning msg="The \"CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2023-04-26T18:45:50+05:00" level=warning msg="The \"CI_COMMIT_SHA\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."     
time="2023-04-26T18:45:50+05:00" level=warning msg="The \"lqxwj\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2023-04-26T18:45:50+05:00" level=warning msg="The \"CI_REGISTRY\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."       
time="2023-04-26T18:45:50+05:00" level=warning msg="The \"CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2023-04-26T18:45:50+05:00" level=warning msg="The \"CI_COMMIT_SHA\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."     
time="2023-04-26T18:45:50+05:00" level=warning msg="The \"lqxwj\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2023-04-26T18:45:50+05:00" level=warning msg="The \"CI_REGISTRY\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."       
time="2023-04-26T18:45:50+05:00" level=warning msg="The \"CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2023-04-26T18:45:50+05:00" level=warning msg="The \"CI_COMMIT_SHA\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."     
time="2023-04-26T18:45:50+05:00" level=warning msg="The \"lqxwj\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2023-04-26T18:45:50+05:00" level=warning msg="The \"CI_REGISTRY\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."       
time="2023-04-26T18:45:50+05:00" level=warning msg="The \"CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2023-04-26T18:45:50+05:00" level=warning msg="The \"CI_COMMIT_SHA\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."     
time="2023-04-26T18:45:50+05:00" level=warning msg="The \"lqxwj\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2023-04-26T18:45:50+05:00" level=warning msg="The \"CI_REGISTRY\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."       
time="2023-04-26T18:45:50+05:00" level=warning msg="The \"CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2023-04-26T18:45:50+05:00" level=warning msg="The \"CI_COMMIT_SHA\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."     
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)
invalid tag "/<gitlab username>/<repository name>/custom_image:-": invalid reference format
```

It doesn't see Gitlab registry variables but how can I start project?

Comment: because gitlab ci is totally counterintuitive stuff